# Запрет выполнения функции для старых Safari

Tags: javascript, webbrowser, safari

Столкнулся с такой проблемой,-  есть необходимость выполнить некий скрипт на `JS`, но поскольку в старых версиях `IOS` для `Iphone 6` (Safari версии 8 и ниже ) некоторые методы из данного скрипта не поддерживаются, а альтернативу придумывать очень долго и трудозатратно. Было принято решение, не запускать выполнение данного скрипта.  Приблизительно так:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("OK");

  function animationCounter() {
    if ((body.width() < 350) && (userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))) {
      console.log('Это яблофон');
      return;
    }

    console.log("Мы пользуемся адекватным браузером, работаем дальше");

  }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

но оказалось что не всё так просто, и парсеру браузера безразлично будет инициализироваться функция, или нет, он просто зависает если не может "прочитать" определенную функцию на момент загрузки страници.
 Вопрос - как это обойти? Как сказать браузеру `Safari v8` и ниже, что если ты чего-то, не можешь сделать, то просто пропусти, а не прерывай выполнения всех остальных скриптов на странице ?

Comment: "парсеру браузера безразлично будет инициализироваться функция, или нет, он просто зависает" - ??

Comment: Он доходит, до тех строк кода которые ему непонятны, и блокирует весь дальнейший код, пока ему не станет синтаксически ясно что от него хотят.

Comment: Пока нам не станет синтаксически ясно, что вы хотите, мы тоже зависнем.

Comment: Как написать функцию которая будет отрабатываться во всех браузерах кроме  мобильного Safari v8 и ниже, с учётом того что в данном браузере не подерживаются некие методы и всё что будет ити после данной функции будет невалидно. работа будет остановлена.(для примера могу предложить метод .addColorStop   - это из работы с canvas) Так надеюсь понятно ?

Comment: Попробуйте перед вызовом функции проверить есть ли она `typeof canvas.addColorStop === 'function'`.